# How do I copy same files with a particular extension to another directory in terminal

Tags: command-line

I want to copy all my .png file to particular directory by using:

```
cp ...../*.png $pwd
```

but it seemed not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command,

```
for i in /path/*.png; do sudo cp $i /path/to/destination/directory; done
```

It will copy all the `.png` files and paste them to the destination directory.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative, try this

```
 cp <path>/*.png <destination-dir>
```

Notice the space between the ***.png** and **destination-dir**. Try to only use/append **sudo** as a prefix if the files your trying to access are restricted to root or other users inaccessible to you directly.